# Uniquely $p$-divisible group-Reference Request.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Define a group $G$ to be uniquely $p$-divisible if for all $x\in G$, there is a unique $y\in G$ such that $x=y^p$. Can someone kindly provide references where this class of groups is studied?

Of course if $G$ is a group of odd order, then it is 2-divisible.

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is finite, then it is uniquely $p$-divisible if and only if $p$ does not divide $|G|$. (This is a generalisation of your example.)

See for example:
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Kth_power_map_is_bijective_iff_k_is_relatively_prime_to_the_order

Comment: Finite part is more or less clear. I was wondering if someone will provide references for such infinite groups.